# Add counter because of conditional statement in other column

Tags: pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements

I am trying to have a conditional counter in a pandas data table. It is supposed to add up when values are below 1, as soon as a value is above 1, the counter is supposed to start again at 0.
I think it's simple, but unfortunately I haven't found the solution.

| Week | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01-2022 | 0.8 | 1 |
| 02-2022 | 0.6 | 2 |
| 03-2022 | 1.5 | 0 |
| 04-2022 | 0.6 | 1 |
| 05-2022 | 0.8 | 2 |
| 06-2022 | 0.8 | 3 |

Thanks for helping me out.

Comment: Sorry, maybe to clarify. 
['A'] is given, ['B'] should be the counter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `groupby.cumcount` for each group starting on a value >0, then correct the first group in case it doesn't start with such a case:

```
# is the value >01?
m = df['A'].gt(1)
# for groups starting on values >1
g = m.groupby(m.cumsum())
# cumcount per group + 1 (-1 if the group starts with a value >1)
df['B'] = g.cumcount().add(1)-g.transform('any')
```

output:

```
      Week    A  B
0  01-2022  0.8  1
1  02-2022  0.6  2
2  03-2022  1.5  0
3  04-2022  0.6  1
4  05-2022  0.8  2
5  06-2022  0.8  3
```

Comment: Thanks again, i have i follow up question. What is the best way to perform this for multible columns? (multible col. like A an multible col. like B)
Thank you for your support

Comment: Probably to `melt`, then use the same approach with the melt index as additional group, finally to `pivot`